# Importing two different projects in the same CMakeList file

Tags: c++, include, cmake, qmake

Regards:

I have two different C++ projects, each one with its own *CMakeList.txt* file that generates a *.so* library file. E.g. both projects are under the paths *trunk/A*, and *trunk/B*, and they contain the files:

- *trunk/A/CMakeList.txt*
- *trunk/B/CMakeLists.txt*

that respectively generate files *A.so* and *B.so*. For practical reasons, I want to keep both projects *A* and *B* separated, but I would also like to have a *CMakeList.txt* file (e.g. *trunk/CMakeList.txt*) that would compile both binaries simultaneously.

I expected to replicate something similar to what can be achieved with *qmake*, by including a *.pri* file in a *.pro* file. Hence, I tried by including both *CMakeList* files with the following code for *trunk/CMakeList.txt*:

```
PROJECT(TEST)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

include(A/CMakeLists.txt)
include(B/CMakeLists.txt)
```

But CMake does not work that way. The contents in the included *CMakeList* files are evaluated from the *trunk* directory. E.g, by reading the following line in *trunk/A/CMakeList.txt*:

```
FILE(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
```

CMake will only look for *.h files in */trunk*, not in */trunk/A*

Is there a proper way to do this in CMake? Something similar to what QMake does with .pri include files?

Hundred thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`:

```
PROJECT(TEST)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( A ) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( B )
```